# Dynamic React Material TextField only focuses on last one created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, material-ui, onfocus

I have an array of goals like so:

```
playerGoals: [
        {
            id: 0,
            goalType: 'A goal type',
            goalName: 'Win the lottery'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            goalType: 'Move career',
            goalName: 'New Job'
        }
    ]
```

I want to map them to an array of components like this:

```
const FormRows = () => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {context.state.playerGoals.map((goal, index) => (
                    <Goal
                        key={index}
                        index={index}
                        goalType={goal.goalType}
                        goalName={goal.goalName}
                        name={goal.goalName}
                    />
                ))}
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
```

And my component contains a material-ui textfield and a handleChange funciton:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log('GOAL', index, event.target.value);
        const goalPayload = {
            index: index,
            value: event.target.value
        };
        dispatch({ type: setGoalName, payload: goalPayload });
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <FormControl className={classes.goalContainer}>
                <FormControlLabel
                    control={
                        <TextField
                            className={classes.goal}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            id="outlined-basic"
                            label={goalType}
                            variant="outlined"
                            value={context.state.playerGoals[index].goalName}
                            inputRef={(input) => input}
                            onFocus={(input) => onFocus(input)}
                        />
                    }
                    label={goalType}
                    labelPlacement="start"
                />
                {getDeleteIcon()}
            </FormControl>
        </Fragment>
    );
```

Whatever I seem to do, the focus always switches back to the latest Goal component I created? How do I refocus to any component I select?

```
const onFocus = (event, input) => {
        input && input.focus();
        // handleChange();
        console.log(event.target.value);
    };
```

Comment: What do you have in `onFocus` function? Could you please post that part as well?

Comment: Its pretty redundant! I wanted to change the inputRef dynamically based on onFocus, but I got stuck!

Comment: Have you had any luck with this one? Just asking out of curiosity

Comment: Yes - I had to put the material-ui components directly into my parent component instead of their being child components. If I'm honest I still didn't understand completely what I did differently so may post my solution as an answer, then if you can post an answer explaining it I will accept yours

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused due to the static id `id="outlined-basic"`.

Could you use a dynamic one, generated based on data passed to this component, to see if this resolves your issue?